# Rails: How to load a specific stylesheet for a specific layout?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm new to Rails and am having trouble getting a layout (which is being used as a unique, static, landing page) to load a specific stylesheet I want to associate with it. E.g.: www.landing.com to load `landing.scss.erb`.

As background, all other routes are going to different pages with different and much more complicated layouts which I have stored in `assets/stylesheets`. E.g.: www.landing.com/A (`a.scss.erb)`; www.landing.com/B (b.scss.erb). The landing page stylesheet is also in `assets/stylesheets` as `landing.scss.erb`.

In my `home controller` I have an action which renders the landing page:

```
def landing
        render :layout => "landing"
    end
```

And in my `routes.rb`: `get 'landing' => 'home#landing'`

In my `views/layouts` I have a file `landing.html.erb` in which I am using `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'landing.scss.erb', media: 'all' %>` in my `head` to try and load this specific stylesheet, however, the landing page is not loading.

If, in my `application.scss` helper file, I include `@import "landing"`, then all of my other pages being dictated by `application.html.erb` will get the `landing.scss.erb` styling which is not what I want.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: So is the entire page not loading (i.e. getting an error) or is it just the style-sheet that isn't loading?

Comment: Also are you using the [root](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) method in your routes file?

Comment: Hi @RyanK, the `landing.html.erb` page is loading, it's just that the stylesheet isn't. I am also using a `root` method to go to `home#index` which includes a `case` statement that directs users to different subdomains and an `else` redirect to the landing page.

Comment: Try putting the "full" path for the stylesheet. I.E. "/assets/stylesheets/landing.scss.erb".

Comment: Didn't work, changed it to `<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/assets/stylesheets/landing.scss.erb', media: 'all' %>`. Still no styles being applied.

Comment: View source, then click on the css link and post any errors.

Comment: Hi @dan-klasson, when I click on the stylesheet that I want loaded (which appears in the source), the error I get is: `No route matches [GET] "/assets/stylesheets/landing.scss.erb.css"`

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was wrong. I believe my syntax for calling the stylesheet in my layout was incorrect.

When I changed it from `<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/assets/stylesheets/landing.scss.erb', media: 'all' %>', media: 'all' %>`

to

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'landing', media: 'all' %>`, I got a new error telling me to add

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( landing.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb`.

I added it, restarted my server and my new layout was correctly rendering the specific stylesheet.

However, I still need to figure out exactly what this precompling code is doing and why it was needed. Any guidance/clarification is appreciated.